# How to vent garage in summer?

Tags: air-conditioning, garage

Our garage faces nearly directly west, meaning it gets full afternoon sun. It also has no attic above it - meaning it has a fair bit of roof. There is batt insulation along the roof but the garage door is not insulated. I *suspect* the exterior drywalled wall is not insulated.

We also have a bedroom above the back half of the garage. Now that it is consistently hot outside we have noticed this bedroom is warm. Our garage interior temperature stays warm late into the night, so we basically are "heating" our house at night because of this (while running the AC).

Is there a standard way to vent a garage in the evenings in summers like this? We have a whole house fan, which allows us to vent the house - perhaps something similar specifically for the garage?

Another option I guess is leaving the garage door open in the evenings... but this feels unreliable as I have to remember to open/shut it and I've already had to chase a rabbit out of our garage once this year...

Comment: You have what's known as a hot roof, which is not ideal in this situation. Ideally you'd have an air space with ventilation between the insulation and the roof itself. This being the case, the only real solution will be substantial ventilation as suggested by Jimmy.

Answer (score 2):

If your roof is constructed with gables, you could use a thermostatically controlled (or timer controlled, or manually switched, or combination of these things) gable fan:

[image]

or cut in a dormer fan or flat powered-attic fan (these are available as a unit, just cut a hole and wire up):

[image]